# Use VBScript to save an Excel file with today's date

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to use a VBScript to save an Excel file with today's date. It opens the workbook, but doesn't save the Excel file with the date. Here's what I have:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Tes\Book1.xlsm")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Activeworkbook.SaveAs "C:\Test\Report\Book1" & 
format Date          (), "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm"
objExcel.Activeworkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Can you show the output of cscript execution?

Answer (score 1):

First - your syntax is broken and path is incomplete on Line 2.

Second - Line 4 is ended with an &. You must end with an underscore (like so: & _) to continue to the next line.

Also line 5, You also cannot format a date like you would in bash, php, or perl. You will have to use functions available, I find this fairly simple.

```
'Will Create a date format yyyymmdd
'Due to unintended line-break in stack overflow this - I've split to 2 lines.
MyDateFormat = Year(now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & _
    Right("0" & Day(now), 2)
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test\Book1.xlsm")
objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Activeworkbook.SaveAs "C:\test\Reports\Book1_" & _
    MyDateFormat & ".xlsm" 'You must append _ to continue to another line.
objExcel.Activeworkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: you saved me. your date format finally worked! Thanks man!